# Is there way to configure nexus as private registry for gke cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nexus

Our docker images are pushed to nexus which is hosted on another gcp machine and our k8s cluster is GKE.

is there a way wherein we can configure nexus as a private registry for gke cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Other users have tried to do this and there's a known issue:

```
Allow user to use 3rd party repository for GKE. Right now we got a x509 error
saying the certificate is signed by unknown authority, meaning Nexus cannot
trust a self signed certificate from GKE. To overcome that, we need to import
the root ca certificate to GKE so both party has the same root of trust, but we are stuck
because we can't import root ca to GKE master.
```

All the reproduction steps are documented in this [public thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/195774978)

NOTE: This public thread is being handled currenlty as a Feature Request which means that Google Cloud is working on this to include it in future GKE versions.

However, I have good news, there's a [public guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gke-and-private-registries-with-self-signed-certificates-b37b5fd1f982) that seems to provide a workaround to fix the known issue.

I hope this information helps you to get your nexus working as a private container registry.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search will do the work :-)

https://blog.sonatype.com/deploy-private-docker-registry-on-google-cloud-platform-with-nexus

Comment: sorry corrected my question, nexus is already configured and we are pushing the images to it, now whenever we create deployments on gke cluster images has to be pulled from already hosted nexus registry

Comment: Also document that you have provided has how to configure nexus in GCP